# Remove list items if it contains text from another list?

Tags: list, python-2.7

MKy programming is a bit rusty. I have a blacklist and want to remove items from another list if the item contains the string from the blacklist. How would I go about accomplishing this in the most pythonic way?

I have no idea where to start so I just wrote this off the top of my head but of course it doesn't work.

```
blacklist = ['.mp3', '.avi', '.jpg' , '.txt', 'ver=3.7.1', '.gif', '.xml', '.css', '.cgi', '.jpg', '.png', '.ico', "wp-content"]

for url in urllist:
    for black in blacklist:
       if black in url:
          urllist.remove(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran the code with a urllist with some blacklisted URLs and some not blacklisted ones and it worked fine. I reckon the error is not in this part of your code but somewhere else.

Comment: You were right I was importing my blacklist from a text file into a list. The text file had spaces in it which was causing my error. thanks!